# Google Places API not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm totally floored here.
I used the Google Places API along with Google Maps Javascript API v3 to display a map of commerces with its address, phone number etc...
I developed the website on Webkit... Then I found out that it just didn't work in Firefox...
Here's my code:

```
function initialize() {
var e = document.getElementById('place_reference')
if (e) {
    var place_reference = document.getElementById('place_reference').innerText;
}
var request = {
  reference: place_reference
};
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
service.getDetails(request, callback);

function callback(place, status) {
  console.log(status);
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
    if (document.getElementById('place_address').innerText == '') {
        document.getElementById('place_address').innerText = place.formatted_address;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('place_phone').innerText == '') {
        document.getElementById('place_phone').innerText = place.international_phone_number;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('place_website').innerHTML == '') {
        document.getElementById('place_website').innerHTML = '<a href="' + place.website + '"target="_blank">' + place.website + '</a>';
    }  
    var place = place.geometry.location;
    var marker;
    var map;
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: place
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: place
    });
  }
}
}
```

On Firefox, the status return INVALID_REQUEST while on other browser, it return OK

I really need help to figure this out. You can check out the website at this address: http://social-e.laclinique.biz/en/blog/shops/noel-eternel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
 var place_reference = document.getElementById('place_reference').innerText;
```

innerText is not supported by FF, use e.g.:

```
 var place_reference = document.getElementById('place_reference').firstChild.nodeValue
```

(or)

```
 var place_reference = document.getElementById('place_reference').innerHTML;
```

Comment: OH MY GOD. I feel stupid there but you were right on! I'll double check the DOM next time. There's a typo in your suggestion btw: firstChild. Cheer!